# Prevent child's onclick after mouseup on parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I have a parent element with `mouse up` and `mouse down` events attached on it, and a child element with a `click` event attached.

Is there any way to prevent the `click` event from happening in the child, after the `mouseup` event has been triggered in the parent?

An example, on the [JSfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6gw4x/28/), the goal is to make the inner square not turn to green if I click on it.

Ideally I would like to do it without modifying the `$('#inner').on('click', function(){})`. I already know that I can set a boolean on `mouseup` and check it on `click` but i'm trying to find a way to do it without modifying the click event.

Using jquery(or any other library) is option and I don't really have any restrictions other than not modifying the `click` method.

**EDIT**

Thanks @adeneo for the suggestion, that looks promising but it made me realize I missed a big part of the problem. Inside `mouseup` there will be a conditional check to see if the click should be prevented or not. If I remove the event can I somehow add it back after the click has been avoided? In a `setTimeout` for example. I'm not sure how(or if it's possible) to get the reference to the removed `click` function and then re-add the handler.

Hopefully this [new fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6gw4x/31/) helps me to explain it a little bit better!

Comment: You can't disable the click event handler without modifying it. Once the mouseup fires you have to use off() to remove the event handler ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6gw4x/30/

Comment: Hello, Please check the Updated Fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/6gw4x/32/
and my EDITTED Answer in this post

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6gw4x/37/

Comment: @adeneo thanks for the suggestion but you modified the click event, it has to be an anonymous function as I can't know what will be there.

Comment: Then no, you can't do that !

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#inner').on('mouseup', function(e) {    
        $(this).unbind("click");
        $(this).css({'background': 'black'});    
});
```

Did you try like this?

Comment: That seems to be the right approach but it leads me to another problem. I've updated my question! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try e.stopImmediatePropagation(); in your inner code.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, can you please update the fiddle with a working sample?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your code with the below code and check. To stop the click event of the inner div you can use preventDefault() or stopPropagation(). Please check below

```
 $('#inner').on('click', function(e) {      
     $(this).stopPropagation();
    // or
    // $(this).preventDefault();
    alert('inner click');
});

$('#outer').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    $(this).css({'background': 'green'});
});

$('#outer').on('mouseup', function(e) {
    $(this).css({'background': 'yellow'});


});
```

Comment: There is no click event in the #outer element. Only mouse up and mouse down. I'm trying to prevent the click of the #inner element, not the other way around.

Comment: jquery objects don't have a stop propagation method, all you did was add an error to the code. I know you're trying to help but at least test the code you're posting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that this is the answer you're looking for :

```
$($(this)).children().click(function (event) { // Preveu la propagació del click als fills 
                // event.stopPropagation();
            });
```

Comment: Has been my answer a  helpfull ??